# column value changes in R group find date difference

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

Suppose I have the following DataFrame

```
ID    Result    Date
1      Pos      4th Jan, 2020
1      Pos      20th Jan, 2020
1      Neg      21st Jan, 2020
2      Pos      5th Jan, 2020
2      Neg      7th Jan, 2020
```

I want to record the **delta (between days)** by ID when the result changes **from positive to negative ONLY**.

so I would like an answer for this test case as:

```
ID    Result    Date               Delta    Time_Spent_Pos
1      Pos      4th Jan, 2020          0              17
1      Pos      20th Jan, 2020        16              17
1      Neg      21st Jan, 2020        17              17
2      Pos      5th Jan, 2020          0               2
2      Neg      7th Jan, 2020          2               2
```

Where I plan to use the time_spent_pos column for further analysis.

## Further Testing Case

I also would like to point out the data could look like

```
ID    Result    Date
1      Neg      12th Dec, 2019
1      Pos      4th Jan, 2020
1      Pos      20th Jan, 2020
1      Neg      21st Jan, 2020
2      Neg      2nd Jan, 2020
2      Pos      5th Jan, 2020
2      Neg      7th Jan, 2020
```

In which case I would still like the old output. So it is important to **find the first time an ID was positive** (Record that forever) -> then find the **first time it changed to negative**. And push the delta to a column.

Any tips + help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to do this calculation. Get the first date where `result = 'Pos'` and subtract it from the immediate next `'Neg'` date.

```
get_delta <- function(res, date) {
  d1 <- date[match('Pos', res)]  
  as.integer(min(date[res == 'Neg' & date > d1]) - d1)
}

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::dmy(Date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Time_Spent_Pos = get_delta(Result, Date)) %>%
  ungroup

#     ID Result Date       Time_Spent_Pos
#  <int> <chr>  <date>     <int>
#1     1 Pos    2020-01-04    17
#2     1 Pos    2020-01-20    17
#3     1 Neg    2020-01-21    17
#4     2 Pos    2020-01-05     2
#5     2 Neg    2020-01-07     2
```

Answer (score 0):

So a simple idea is to create two separate columns one whenever the value is positive and another whenever the value is negative then grouping and getting minimum/maximum values for each of these columns.

Here is how you can do it;

```
# Reading required libraries
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Create sample dataframes
df <-
  data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
             Result = c("Neg", "Pos", "Pos", "Neg", "Neg", "Pos", "Neg"),
             Date = c("12th Dec, 2019", "4th Jan, 2020", "20th Jan, 2020",
                      "21st Jan, 2020", "2nd Jan, 2020", "5th Jan, 2020",
                      "7th Jan, 2020"))

df %>%
  # Convert date into yyyy-mm-dd to easily manipulate it
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date),
         # In case positive/negative then create a column with value
         POSITIVE = as.Date(ifelse(Result == "Pos", Date, NA), origin = lubridate::origin),
         NEGATIVE = as.Date(ifelse(Result == "Neg", Date, NA), origin = lubridate::origin)) %>%
  # Grouping by ID
  group_by(ID) %>%
  # Getting firs positive and last negative 
  mutate(POSITIVE = min(POSITIVE, na.rm = TRUE),
         NEGATIVE = max(NEGATIVE, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # Calculating difference between positive and negative
  mutate(Time_Spent_Pos = NEGATIVE - POSITIVE)
```