# Add Fail datetime to next Pass event, and reduce to single event

Tags: r

Excuse what might be a basic question, but I’m still learning r.
I have a data frame that contains test results, it includes project name, a resource identifier, a single date-time field, and Boolean value for the result of the test, ‘test_fail’=TRUE equates to a failed test.

**Example Data:**

```
test_data <- data.frame(
  project_name = c("project-1","project-1","project-1","project-2","project-1","project-2","project-1","project-2",
                   "project-2","project-1","project-1","project-3","project-3","project-3","project-2","project-3","project-2","project-2"),
  grp_res = c("A","A","D","B","D","B","A","B","B","D","D","E","E","E","B","E","B","B"),
  test_fail = as.logical(c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)),
  test_dt = ymd_hm(c("2023-05-01 08:45", "2023-05-01 09:10","2023-05-01 11:00","2023-05-01 14:00", "2023-05-02 09:00",
                      "2023-05-02 14:00","2023-05-03 09:10","2023-05-03 10:10","2023-05-03 14:10","2023-05-03 17:00",
                     "2023-05-04 09:30","2023-05-04 11:30","2023-05-05 13:30","2023-05-06 08:00","2023-05-06 16:00","2023-05-07 10:20","2023-05-10 08:30","2023-05-10 17:30")),
  test_status = as.numeric(c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I tried both solutions suggested here: [column value changes in R group find date difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68447878/column-value-changes-in-r-group-find-date-difference)

as this looked very close to what I'm attempting to achieve, but it did not work for me, possibly due to me having a datetime field.

I want to capture the datetime ‘test_dt’ for a failed test and then look forward to the next test that changed to a pass for the given ‘project_name’ and ‘grp_res’, assign the failed datetime value to a new column for the event that passed.

Ultimately, I would like the data to look like the example below:

| project_name | grp_res | test_fail | test_dt | test_status | failed_dt | fixed_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| project-1 | A | TRUE | 2023-05-01 08:45:00 | 1 | 2023-05-01 08:45:00 | 2023-05-01 09:10:00 |
| project-2 | B | TRUE | 2023-05-02 14:00:00 | 1 | 2023-05-02 14:00:00 | 2023-05-03 14:10:00 |
| project-2 | B | TRUE | 2023-05-10 08:30:00 | 1 | 2023-05-10 08:30:00 | 2023-05-10 17:30:00 |
| project-1 | D | TRUE | 2023-05-03 17:00:00 | 1 | 2023-05-03 17:00:00 | 2023-05-04 09:30:00 |
| project-3 | E | TRUE | 2023-05-05 13:30:00 | 1 | 2023-05-05 13:30:00 | 2023-05-07 10:20:00 |

```
final_data <- data.frame(
  project_name = c("project-1","project-2","project-2","project-1","project-3"),
  grp_res = c("A","B","B","D","E"),
  test_fail = as.logical(c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)),
  test_dt = ymd_hm(c("2023-05-01 08:45","2023-05-02 14:00","2023-05-10 08:30","2023-05-03 17:00","2023-05-05 13:30")),
  failed_dt = ymd_hm(c("2023-05-01 08:45","2023-05-02 14:00","2023-05-10 08:30","2023-05-03 17:00","2023-05-05 13:30")),
  fixed_dt = ymd_hm(c("2023-05-01 09:10","2023-05-03 14:10","2023-05-10 17:30","2023-05-04 09:30","2023-05-07 10:20")),
  test_status = as.numeric(c(1,1,1,1,1)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I've been scratching my head on this one, and spent more than a few hours looking for other possible solutions on Stackoverflow, with no luck.

And help and tips will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be (conditional) join. The dataset is first split by `test_fail` values, items in resulting list are named `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"`. The part with failures is kept as-is, while for the other only `proj_name`, `grp_res` & `fixed_dt`(renamed `test_dt`) columns are kept. When joining both parts, only the first match from the right side is selected. And to handle cases where different failures have been matched to the same `fixed_dt` value, `slice_min()` with relevant grouping keeps only the first failure.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

split(test_data, ~ t_fail) %>% 
  map_at("FALSE", \(df_) select(df_, proj_name, grp_res, fixed_dt = test_dt)) %>% 
  { left_join(.$`TRUE`, .$`FALSE`, 
            by = join_by(proj_name, grp_res, test_dt < fixed_dt), 
            multiple = "first")
  } %>% 
  slice_min(test_dt, by = c(proj_name, grp_res, fixed_dt)) %>% 
  arrange(test_dt) 
#>   proj_name grp_res t_fail             test_dt t_status            fixed_dt
#> 1 project-1       A   TRUE 2023-05-01 09:10:00        1 2023-05-03 09:10:00
#> 2 project-2       B   TRUE 2023-05-02 14:00:00        1 2023-05-03 14:10:00
#> 3 project-1       D   TRUE 2023-05-03 17:00:00        1 2023-05-04 09:30:00
#> 4 project-3       E   TRUE 2023-05-05 13:30:00        1 2023-05-07 10:20:00
#> 5 project-2       B   TRUE 2023-05-10 08:30:00        1 2023-05-10 17:30:00
```

Input data:

```r
test_data <- data.frame(
  proj_name = c("project-1","project-1","project-1","project-2","project-1","project-2","project-1","project-2",
                   "project-2","project-1","project-1","project-3","project-3","project-3","project-2","project-3","project-2","project-2"),
  grp_res = c("A","A","D","B","D","B","A","B","B","D","D","E","E","E","B","E","B","B"),
  t_fail = as.logical(c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)),
  test_dt = ymd_hm(c("2023-05-01 08:45", "2023-05-01 09:10","2023-05-01 11:00","2023-05-01 14:00", "2023-05-02 09:00",
                     "2023-05-02 14:00","2023-05-03 09:10","2023-05-03 10:10","2023-05-03 14:10","2023-05-03 17:00",
                     "2023-05-04 09:30","2023-05-04 11:30","2023-05-05 13:30","2023-05-06 08:00","2023-05-06 16:00","2023-05-07 10:20","2023-05-10 08:30","2023-05-10 17:30")),
  t_status = as.numeric(c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Awesome, test with live data and work perfectly. thanks so much.